# Displaying multiple screens in conductor doesn't work

Tags: c#, mvvm, caliburn.micro, caliburn

I want to display a couple of screens at the same time. Displaying only one screen works fine, but when I switch my conductor to `Conductor<DMChartBase>.Collection.AllActive` and add another item, it still renders only one item.

```
public class DocumentViewModel : Conductor<DMChartBase>.Collection.AllActive
{
    public ChartLegendViewModel ChartLegendVm { get; set; }

    public DocumentViewModel()
    {
         ChartLegendVm = new ChartLegendViewModel();
         ActivateItem(ChartLegendVm);
    }

    public void ChangeChart(DMChartBase chart, Column[] columns)
    {
        ActivateItem(chart);
        Items.Last().Init(columns);
        Items.Refresh();
    }
}
```

And `DocumentView`:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="Items"></ItemsControl>
```

I cannot find any reason why this doesn't work. Any ideas?

EDIT:
My code structure looks like this:

```
public class ShellViewModel : Screen
    public class DocumentViewModel : Conductor<DMChartBase>.Collection.AllActive
        public class ChartLegendViewModel : ChartDecorator
            public abstract class ChartDecorator : DMChartBase
                 public abstract class DMChartBase : Screen
```

**DocumentView**:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="Items">
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**ChartLegendView**:

```
<UserControl ....>
    <ListView>
        <ListViewItem Content="First value"></ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem Content="Second value"></ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem Content="Third value"></ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
</UserControl>
```

**Bootstrapper**:

```
protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    DisplayRootViewFor<ShellViewModel>()
}
```

**EDIT:**
I figured it out!
Previously I wanted to instantiate Chart and Legend separately which is wrong. `DocumentViewModel` should only be responsible for instantiating `ChartDecorator`. Inside `ChartDecorator` I can create as many decorator classes as I want (such as ChartLegendViewModel) and they all get drawn.

Comment: what container are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IoC isn't used at all?  Secondly can you show us bootstrapper and XAML would help alittle.  Are these items in a separate library?  Normally Conductor uses a Screen or IScreen to have access to the "screens" lifetime. So unless DMChartBase inherits screen(IScreen) I don't think you will get an activation...

```
//MEF IoC Container -- CM Built-in
[Export(typeof(MainWindowViewModel))]
public class MainWindowViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MainWindowViewModel([ImportMany]IEnumerable<IScreen> screens)
    {
        DisplayName = "COmposition Example - CM";


        Items.AddRange(screens.Reverse());
    }

    protected override void OnActivate()
    {
        ActivateItem(Items[0]);
    }
}
```

as an example... It shows all of them but only one is Active if you change it to AllActive they all would be active "can inter-communicate" but they aren't visible due to constraints of the control, used for this case (tab control) but if it was changed to an itemscontrols you still need to some work since the view wouldn't know how to deal with the binding of the view to the viewmodel

Comment: I didn't use IoC, everything is in the same project. This is very basic setup, because I just wanted to add a decorator pattern that wraps legend for my charts. I'm very surprised that it doesn't work to be honest. DMChartBase is just a screen with additional options for my charts, like columns, name etc. I updated my question, so you can see what views look like.